# String to datagrid

Tags: asp.net

Whats the best component to use to add data to a grid?

I have a string which I will split by char, I then want to add the seperate strings to a row.

I know that C# has a datagridview but this doesnt seem to be available in ASP.

Any other suggestions for the easiest component to use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Personally is Repeater http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx